# Python passing return values to functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that will generate a random list, length being determined by user input, that will be sorted. I'm having a problem accessing/passing my randomly generated list to other functions. For example, below, I can't print my list **x**. I've also tried making a function specifically for printing the list, yet that won't work either. How can I pass the list **x**?

```
unsorted_list = []
sorted_list = []

# Random list generator
def listgen(y):
    """Makes a random list"""
    import random
    x = []
    for i in range(y):
        x.append(random.randrange(100))
        i += 1
    return x

def main():
    y = int(input("How long would you like to make the list?: "))
    listgen(y)
    print(x)


main()
```

Comment: x is local to listgen()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = listgen(y)
print(l)
```

The variable `x` is local to `listgen()`. To get the list inside of `main()`, assign the return value to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

`x = listgen(y)`

```
def main():
    y = int(input("How long would you like to make the list?: "))
    x = listgen(y)
    print(x)
```

x should be assigned based on return value of your function

Answer (score 0):

In your main, this:

```
def main():
    y = int(input("How long would you like to make the list?: "))
    listgen(y)
    print(x)
```

should be:

```
def main():
    y = int(input("How long would you like to make the list?: "))
    x = listgen(y) # Must assign the value returned to a variable to use it
    print(x)
```

Does that make sense?